# Actionbar 'action button' disabling/enabling programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Back with another one. Trying to get what little app I have to cooperate with 3.0+ Android versions, and have something i'm not sure how to handle..

I have an options menu, which I upgraded to better suit the Action bar, defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_sheet_photo_comp" android:title="@string/menu_sheet_photo" android:id="@+id/mnuCamera" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_sheet_notes_comp" android:title="@string/menu_sheet_notes" android:id="@+id/mnuLogText" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_compose" />
    <item android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_sheet_track_comp" android:title="@string/menu_sheet_track" android:id="@+id/mnuTrack" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />
    <item android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_sheet_geocache_comp" android:title="@string/menu_sheet_geocache" android:id="@+id/mnuGC" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_emoticons" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

This all works fine as is - when the activity is run, the photo (first one) is displayed on the action bar on my phone, none of othe others are. Now, the options availability depend on a few things.

So, at the beginning of the Activity launch, a thread is sent off to get web data. And `onCreateOptionsMenu()` I disable the first item. (They cannot take a photo of it until we get web data back verifying it can be photographed.)

On previous versions of my app, it was easy - on `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` I check the status, and then enable or disable the options, as appropriate. Now, here's what I can't figure out how to do -

Since the camera button's on the action bar, and not in the overflow menu, when the user taps it, `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is never called, so the button stays disabled.

So how would I be able to make that button enabled once my background thread returns and I know that I can enable it?

Cheers -
Mike.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either call invalidateOptionsMenu() and add a check in onCreateOptionsMenu() for the enabling/disabling or create the menus programmatically and hold the Menu instance somewhere, so you can enable it later.

Comment: Beautiful, that was easier than I was anticipating!

Answer (score 2):

What stoilkov said above is the approach I use.  More explicitly, at the point where your background thread returns, set a flag, lets call it isCamButtonEnabled, to false and then make the call to invalidateOptionsMenu().  This will trigger onCreateOptionsMenu to be invoked to regenerate your menu.  The final piece is to modify your onCreateOptionsMenu to disable the camera button depending on the state of isCamButtonEnabled.  You can either do this by loading a completely different menu resource:

```
if(isCamButtonEnabled) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cam_enabled_menu, menu);
} else {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cam_disabled_menu, menu);   
}
```

or always load the same menu resource and just disable or hide the camera button after the fact.

Comment: Code Optimization in One line `getMenuInflater().inflate(isCamButtonEnabled ? R.menu.cam_enabled_menu : R.menu.cam_disabled_menu, menu);`